# Android Room populate database with new data after migration?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-migration, android-room

I already published an application in Play Store which pre-populate Room database with data in the `onCreate` callback. The data is read from a JSON file and put it into the database. Everything works for data into the database (add new records into table) again from a JSON file.

Here is my RoomDatabase `create` method:

```
private fun create(context: Context): MyDatabase {
        val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE dogs ADD COLUMN language TEXT")
            }
        }
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            context.applicationContext,
            MyDatabase::class.java,
            DB_NAME
        )
            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
            // prepopulate the database after onCreate was called
            .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                    super.onCreate(db)
                    GlobalScope.launch {
                        getInstance(context)?.let { DatabaseUtils.prepopulateDatabase(context, it) }
                    }
                }
            })
            .build()
    }
```

Is there an easy way to do that without to write hundreds SQL requests manually?
Or if there is a way how to drop the whole database and create a new one with brand new data, maybe also will be an option for me.

Thanks in advance guys ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is the easiest way:

```
private const val IS_DB_RECREATED = "is_database_recreated"

class App : Application(), HasActivityInjector {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        val isDBRecreated = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(IS_DB_RECREATED, false)

        if (!isDBRecreated) {
            deleteDatabase(MyDatabase.DB_NAME)
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(IS_DB_RECREATED, true).apply()
        }
    }
}
```

The all data will be lost from the database, but when the new DB is access for the first time it will be pre-populated and I can change the scheme also.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop/clear the previous db by using fallbackToDestructiveMigration.

```
database = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    UsersDatabase.class, "Sample.db")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build();
```

Refer scenario 3 from this google article [Understanding migrations with Room](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929)

Comment: But scenario 3 from this article said: "So now, our app doesn’t crash, but we lose all the data. So be sure that this is how you specifically want to handle migrations.". Is that means the database will be empty or it will be recreated and in the first access the callback "onCreate" will be called again and the database will be pre-populated again with the new data?

Comment: @MrVasilev - It will clear and won't pre populate. How about you give it a test??

Comment: Yes, this also a good question, How to test an update from Play Store, because when try to test new version in emulator just say that "You already have an application with this package Do you want to uninstall it?" and just uninstall the app and install it again, which is not real update from Play Store, right? :)

Comment: @MrVasilev - You can upload the latest version in alpha and add specific users for testing.Hence you will be able to test that way. Here is the link https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments 
And in Production do a stage rollout first to 1% users than 10% and so on.